# Prove that there is some positive integer $n$ such that $n, n +1, n+2,... , n + 200$ are all composite.

Tags: number-theory

Have following approach, which either is inadequate or am unable to amend for this problem:

1. By definition, if $n\le m$, then $n \,|\, m!$.
2. Thus for all integers $2\le n\le (m + 1)$, $n \,|\, (m + 1)!$.
3. For all integers, $n \,| \,n$ trivially.
4. Also, if $n\, |\, a$ and $n\, | 
      \,b\implies n\, | \,(a + b)$, with $a = n, b= (m+1)!$.
5. Hence, have : $$2\,|\, 2 +(m+1)!$$  $$3\,|\, 3 +(m+1)!$$ $$\vdots$$  $$n+1\,|\, n +1+(m+1)!$$

Comment: Good idea, but you are using the letter $n$ for two different things.

Comment: If the question is to check that this is a full proof, please state the points which you find suspicious in it.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I feel my edit is valid and satisfies your issue too.

Comment: And for the $1+(m+1)!$ don't forget the [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem)

Comment: @Did This approach can be used to prove a super-set, i.e. say : $n\, |\, n +200!$, if $n \le 200$; but to prove that $n\,|\, n + 200$ is not obvious still.

Comment: @rtybase Am reading this theorem first time. Please guide, as it seems to work for prime $n$ only.

Comment: @jiten you need an $n=m!, m \geq 200$, then $m!+2,m!+3,...,m!+200$ are composite ... you need to be careful with $m!+1$, for that see my previous comment ... so you need a prime $p> 200$ and $n=(p-1)!$

Comment: jiten: "to prove that n|n+200 is not obvious still." Sorry but what? Where do you see that one would need to prove that n divides n+200?

Comment: @Did $n \,|\,n+200!\implies n\,|\, n$ & $n\,|\,200!$. It means to me that: $n$ divides any (at least one) product term in $200!$. I feel the two issues -- (a) having  $n\,|\, 200$, if $2\le n\le 200$, (b) $n\,|\, 200!$, if $2\le n\le 200$, are separate with (b) being obvious. While (a) is needed one, but not obvious and is separate than (b).

Comment: jiten: But not every $n$ in $[2,200]$ divides $200$ hence (a) is hopeless... Congrats, you lost me (in what you know and do not know and try and do not try, not in the way to prove the result, which is crystal clear).

Comment: @Did That's what I am stating, $n$ will divide at least one term in $200!$, so how can I say $n \,|\, 200$; or $n \,|\, 199$, etc. This is why I put this question.  For me $n+l, l\in \{n,200\}$ is composed of two terms $n, l$ and both need be shown to be divisible by $n$. How to show $n\,|\, l$ is unclear.

Comment: Still undecipherable, sorry. Anyway, do you consider that the answer you instantly chose to accept, is addressing these?

Comment: @Did To continue with my last comment, it is possible that my view to see problem (as above) is wrong, but not seeing the error.

Comment: Why do you avoid the precise question I am asking? This attitude has consequences, in the real world and even, sometimes, on MSE, you know.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+200!%2B1

Comment: The stretch of (at least) 200 composite numbers is known as a *prime gap*.  See the Wikipedia article for more information.  Simple number theory considerations suffice to establish the existence of arbitrarily long prime gaps in the integers, as study of the Answers below will show.  We don't need to go out as far as $200!+2$ to begin a prime gap of length 200 or more.  With a bit of programming one finds that following prime $20831323$ there is a prime gap of length $209$.  This gives something of an indication of what is known by simple reasoning versus what requires "tools" to work out.

Comment: @all If the question is good, then someone please up-vote to prevent from deletion by system ( as I feel negative vote would cause automatically, after some fixed interval).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you were doing is correct. What you need is a clever choice for $n$. Choose $n=202!+2$ and it'll work out.

Comment: Please elaborate, am not clear.

Comment: It is clear that $n \mid 202!+n$ for $2 \leq n \leq 202$. That's what you need.

Comment: But, then why need a 'clever choice'. It is not obvious to me - the significance of that. For me, it means : if $2\le n \le m+1\implies n\,|\, (m+1)!$.

Comment: Yeah. But that's exactly what's needed. You need at least $201$ such numbers. Hence $n>201$. Anything above $202$ works too. 'Clever' because it doesn't involve any checking, just simple algebraic trickery.

Answer (score 2):

Rephrasing:

$k_1 = 2+(n)!, k_2 =3+(n)!,....$

$...k_{n-1} = (n) +(n)!$.

All of the above numbers $k_i, i=1,2,...,(n-1)$ are composite.

To have $201$ consecutive composite numbers choose

$n= 202$.

This way you can have arbitrarily large gaps between consecutive primes.

Ref:Wiki: Prime gaps

Comment: If the question is good, then please up-vote to prevent from deletion by system ( as I feel negative vote would cause automatically, after some fixed interval).

Comment: jiten +1.Good question .Good effort.Keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=(200!)^{3} \in \mathbb{N}$ (absurd number, I know). Then

\begin{alignat}{3}
200 &| n &&= & & (200!)^{3} \\
  &      &&= & & 200(199!)(200!)^{2} \\
& && & & \\
m &| n+1 &&= & & (200!)^{3}+1 \\
  &      &&= & & (200!)^{3}-(-1)^{3} \\
  &      &&= & & [200!-(-1)][(200!)^{2}+(-1)^{1}(200!)^{1}+(-1)^{2}] \\
  &      &&= & & [200!+1][(200!)^{2}-200!+1] \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \text{ (and so let } m=200!+1\in \mathbb{N}) \\
& && & & \\
3 &| n+3 &&= & & (200!)^{3}+3 \\
  &      &&= & & 3[(1 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 \cdot … \cdot 200)(200!)^{2}+1] \\
&... && & & \\ 
199 &| n+199 &&= & & (200!)^{3}+199 \\
 &       &&= & & 199[(1 \cdot 2 \cdot … \cdot 198 \cdot 200)(200!)^{2} + 1] \\
& && & & \\
200 &| n+200 &&= & & (200!)^{3}+200 \\
 &       &&= & & 200[(199!)(200!)^{2} + 1]. \\
\end{alignat}
QED.